# .NET Multiple Entity Models using Multiple DB's in the same VS2010 Project

Tags: sql-server-2005, entity-framework, .net-4.0

Greetings everyone!

Here's the deal, I've got a site that has multiple languages, each language has its own MSSQL database. I tried to add an Entity Framework Data Model for each database, only to find that the partial classes are conflicting with the other EF Data Models.  So the column "banner" from one Model conflicts with the column "banner from another Model.  I'm trying to make this as universal as possible by not naming the columns differently but instead dynamically changing the Model I'm using when a specific language is selected.

Any ideas?  I'd really appreciate the help!

Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If those DB have same schema, all you need is one model. Then based on user's language, connect to relevant DB.

Comment: Thanks!  I don't know why I didn't think of that.  I guess now I'll have to check to see if the table structures or SP's change.